# How can I best run a MySQL SELECT query between two tables in Node JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a pretty long SELECT query I have attempted to save to a variable (queryString) in my app.js file. It's throwing a SQL syntax error and I'm just not getting it. It appears I am not escaping my double quote on the string "February" because the error message shows a transient single quote at the end like "February"'. How am I getting that additional single quote at the end? Or is that really what's causing the error?

Also, is there a more appropriate method for passing a query like this? Like, can you store it in an .sql file and import that into the app.js file?

I know the query works because I can run it from the terminal with expected results.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN m.item_trx_qty > 0 THEN m.item_trx_qty * (s.old_cost - m.liuom_unit_price_amt) ELSE 0 END as `Savings`,
        s.coid as `COID`,
        s.fee_id as `Fee ID`,
        s.sw_idea_num as `SW Idea Num`,
        s.description as `Item Description`  
    FROM
        monthly_usage m, smart_items s
    WHERE
        m.coid = s.coid
        AND m.fin = s.fin
        AND m.u_year = 2019
        AND m.u_month = "February"
    GROUP BY s.sw_idea_num
    ORDER BY s.sw_idea_num
    ;
```

This is the snippet from my app.js file:

```
// For savings data from the saving query
const queryString = "SELECT CASE WHEN m.item_trx_qty > 0 THEN m.item_trx_qty * (s.old_cost - m.liuom_unit_price_amt) ELSE 0 END as `Savings`, " + 
                    "s.coid as `COID`, s.fee_id as `Fee ID`, s.sw_idea_num as `SW Idea Num`, s.description as `Item Description`" +  
                    "FROM monthly_usage m, smart_items s" +
                    "WHERE m.coid = s.coid " +
                    "AND m.fin = s.fin " +
                    "AND m.u_year = 2019 " +
                    "AND m.u_month = \"February\"" +
                    "GROUP BY s.sw_idea_num " +
                    "ORDER BY s.sw_idea_num;"

const savings = connection.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
    console.log('Fetched savings successfully!')
        })
```

Here is the error I am getting:

Failed to query for savings Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm.coid = s.coid AND m.fin = s.fin AND m.u_year
= 2019 AND m.u_month = "February"' at line 1

Comment: You need a space after the final s here: `"FROM monthly_usage m, smart_items s" +`

Comment: Also at the end of the lines with `Item Description` and `February` in them.

Comment: You may also need a space between the two double quotes in \"February\""

Comment: It would be easier if you used a template string, so you can put line breaks in the string itself instead of all those error-prone concatenations.

Comment: Use `console.log(queryString)` to see the final string, then you should see where you need spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! This was just the solution I was looking for once I converted it over to a string literal.